# How to expose salesforce calendar using REST API?

Tags: rest-service

i need to get and set salesforce calendar data , using rest api , but i can't find any REST API do what i want anyway to do this ?

Comment: Hi Ryan. What did you try so far? Could you post your code?

Comment: Hello Guy Clairbois. i am searching for rest api that enable me to get my calendar data on salesforce and post events on it using asp untill now i can't find any rest api that enable me to do so any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create Event records using the standard Salesforce REST API.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm

Create a record:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm

So for creating records of type 'Event' you will use this url:

```
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/
Event/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@newaccount.json"
```

And a request body that fills the Event fields:

```
{
  "Subject" : "My Calendar Event",
  "OwnerId" : "00580000001YeviAAC",
  "DurationInMinutes" : "60",
  "ActivityDateTime" : "2020-05-04T20:00:00.000"
}
```

etc

Example call to fetch Event details:

```
/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Event/00U3c00000mC99OEAS?fields=Subject,DurationInMinutes,ActivityDateTime
```

Definition of the Event object in Salesforce:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Event.htm